# Acquire Internet Explorer window position

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How do I get in Internet Explorer values equivalent to: window.screenX and window.screenY in Firefox ?
I've seen some "solution": window.screenLeft and window.screenTop but it is *not* correct. These properties give inner coordinates.

I move a window and I need values to use with window.moveTo() to restore the original location.

Answer (score 2):

```
var saveLeft = window.screenLeft;
var saveTop = window.screenTop;
window.moveTo(saveLeft, saveTop);
var savePos = [
    saveLeft + (saveLeft - window.screenLeft), 
    saveTop + (saveTop - window.screenTop)
];
```

Seems to work

Comment: Then you go and move the window however you want. When you want to restore the original position use window.moveTo(savePos[0], savePos[1]) .

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent properties don't appear to exist for Internet Explorer windows.  Have you seen the [`window.resizeBy(w, h)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536722(VS.85).aspx) method?  Using that you could grow by a specific amount and then shrink back down using negative values (or vice versa):

```
window.resizeBy(300, 300);  // expand window by 300x300 pixels

window.setTimeout(function ()
{
    window.resizeBy(-300, -300); // back to original size
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed the question and edited it. Looks like you were answering the original meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

There are years since i did any MSIE programming, but i roughly remember using something like this

- save  screenLeft and Top as window postion (this is wrong but read on)
- when restoring the position, window.moveTo(saved position)
- (current screenLeft > saved Left) window.moveBy(-1,0)
- the same for y position

the idea is that we place the window in a wrong position first and then correct it step by step

Comment: Thanks! I'll try a bit later some solution based on this idea. I'm thinking about moving the window to the wrong position, calculating the diff and moving once again.

Comment: My code based on your ideas seems to work for now. Thanks again!